# Can I choose between click and scroll in Jquery?

Tags: jquery, events, click, scroll

I have two events:

```
$('#item').click(function...
```

and

```
$(window).scroll(function...
```

The click event scrolls the page. However I want to prevent the function of the scroll event only when the click event is called.

When the user scrolls the page by hand, then I want the scroll event to take control. I have tried unbinding the scroll event then binding again once the click event completes but that didn't work.

any ideas?

Comment: thanks Flix Kling, forgot to tag the code. Sorry.

Comment: also, I've tried .stopPropagation

Answer (score 0):

i got it to work that way:

http://jsfiddle.net/r9XAN/

```
$(window).scroll(scroll);

$('a').click(function(ev){
    $(window).unbind('scroll').scrollTop(100);
    setTimeout(function(){
        $(window).scroll(scroll);
    },1);
    ev.preventDefault();
});

function scroll(){
    console.log('scrolled'); 
}
```

It's a bit strange. If you rebind the scroll event immediately it won't work. With a timeout of 1 it does. (on chrome at least)